# static attribute inside a class not accessible with object in PHP

Tags: php

```
class Foo
{
    public static $my_static = 'foo';

    public static function staticValue() {
        return self::$my_static;
    }
}


$foo = new Foo();
print $foo->staticValue() . "\n";
print $foo->my_static . "\n";
```

Why the static attribute is not accessible while static resources are accessible using object in PHP.It is only accessible using '::'.

Comment: Because `->` is for class members. "In the object represented by this variable, print out the member with this name". `::` for static values translates to "no matter which instance of this object this may be, print out this static value that's present in ALL copies of the object".

Comment: @MarcB:so property or an attribute of a class is not a member of the class?

Comment: sure, it's a member. but since it's a static property, it's present in ALL instances of the object.

Comment: @MarcB:so can i conclude it like this. "staic methods are only accessible using ::"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have 2 "scopes" one is the "object" and one is the "static" within every class.
So the same problem occurs of you want to execute a normal method within a static method.
For example:

```
class foo {
 public function bar() {
  echo "bar";
 } 

 public static function bar2() {
   echo $this->bar();
 }
}

$foo = new foo();
$foo->bar2();
```

That is because the you are in a static context and the object context is not accessable from there.
I think, more it can not be said about this.
See it like you have a house with 2 familys which lives in it and the doors between them can NEVER be open.
You have one global house which is the class and then family 1 which is the object scope and finally family 2 which is the static scope.

Maybe this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access it using scope resolution operator ::

```
echo  $foo::my_static . "\n";
```

Comment: :I know that.But my question is why.Since it is a member of that class foo why i can't user the object to access it